# How to change which partition is the C drive after copying?

Tags: ssd

I bought an SSD. I want to make the SSD to copy the exact partition of my current C drive.

After that I want the SSD to be my C drive. How would I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try remove the old drive. Set ssd drive to be the boot drive in bios.

Comment: I do not want to remove the old drive. I want both to be there.,

Comment: Theb Just make the change in bios.